# jQuery DataTables empty data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables which I populate it via server-side/ajax. The table is populated successfully, however, I attempt the access the DataTable via this.api() inside of the initComplete callback and I am returned an empty array. My understanding is initComplete callback should only be called once the table is populated/drawn and the data is present. Any ideas why the table is populated but this.api() returns empty?

Comment: What is the code you are trying? Is the table loaded at the same time as the  DOM?

Comment: this.api() should never return anything empty, it should return an api instance, also if the dataset is empty. Can you show the code you are using? Perhaps reproduce the behaviour in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not that this.api() was empty, though I find it weird that it prints '[]' when consoling it. The issue is I had a chained command, this.api().columns().every(...), but I have version 1.10.1, which does not have the every(...) method.